# Why Java 8 Stream forEach method behaves differently?

Tags: java, foreach, lambda, functional-programming, java-8

As per my understanding of java 8 lambda expressions, if we don't include code after "->" in curly braces that value will be returned implicitly. But in case of below example, `forEach` method expects `Consumer` and expression returns value but the compiler is not giving an error in Eclipse.

```
List<StringBuilder> messages = Arrays.asList(new StringBuilder(), new StringBuilder());

messages.stream().forEach(s-> s.append("helloworld"));//works fine 

messages.stream().forEach((StringBuilder s)-> s.append("helloworld")); //works fine 

messages.stream().forEach(s-> s); // doesn't work , Void methods cannot return a value

messages.stream().forEach(s-> s.toString()); // works fine

messages.stream().forEach(s-> {return s.append("helloworld");}); // doesn't work , Void methods cannot return a value

messages.stream().forEach((StringBuilder s)-> {return s.append("helloworld");});  // doesn't work , Void methods cannot return a value
```

`s.append` returns `StringBuilder` and `s.toString()` returns `String` but lambda treats it as `void`.

What am I missing here? Why isn't the compiler giving an error when we invoke method on object?

Answer (score 13):

From [JLS 15.27.3. Type of a Lambda Expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27.3):

> A lambda expression is congruent with a function type if all of the
>   following are true:
>
> - The function type has no type parameters.
> - The number of lambda parameters is the same as the number of parameter types of the function type.
> - If the lambda expression is explicitly typed, its formal parameter types are the same as the parameter types of the function type.
>
>   - If the lambda parameters are assumed to have the same types as the function type's parameter types, then:
>   - **If the function type's result is void, the lambda body is either a statement expression (§14.8) or a void-compatible block**.
>   - If the function type's result is a (non-void) type R, then either i) the lambda body is an expression that is compatible with R
>       in an assignment context, or ii) the lambda body is a value-compatible
>       block, and each result expression (§15.27.2) is compatible with R in
>       an assignment context.

The highlighted sentence above means that any statement lambda expression (i.e. a lambda expression without a block) matches a functional interface whose single method's return type is `void` (such as the `Consumer` functional interface required by the `forEach` method).

This explains why `s.append("helloworld")` & `s.toString()` (your 1,2 & 4 examples) work fine as statement lambda expressions.

examples 5 & 6 don't work, since those have block lambda bodies which are value-compatible lambda expressions. To be `void-compatible`, all the return statements must return nothing (i.e. just `return;`).

On the other hand, the following `void-compatible` block lambda bodies will pass compilation :

```
messages.stream().forEach(s-> {s.append("helloworld");});
messages.stream().forEach(s-> {s.append("helloworld"); return;});
```

Your 4th example - `messages.stream().forEach(s-> s);` doesn't work for the same reason the following method doesn't pass compilation :

```
void method (StringBuilder s)
{
    s;
}
```

Comment: It might be worth expanding that `s` doesn’t work because `s` is an *expression* but not a *statement expression* as demanded for `void`-compatible lambda expressions by the highlighted sentence. A *statement expression* can be a method invocation (as shown in the examples) or an assignment, e.g. `x -> foo=x` or an increment/decrement operation, e.g. `x -> count++`. The intuitive explanation by example, that everything works which you could write as a statement as in `void method (StringBuilder s) { statementExpression; }` is correct.

Answer (score 4):

From [`java.util.stream.Stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-), the signature of `forEach` is:

> `void forEach(Consumer<? super T> action)`

From [`java.util.function.Consumer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html#accept-T-), the `action` must implement the following method:

> `void accept(T t)`

In all your examples that don't work, you're returning a `T`, which doesn't match the return type of `void`.

> Why compiler is not giving error when we invoke method on object?

Because you're not trying to `return` something, the lambda's return type is `void`, which matches the required `Consumer` signature.

The only possible type for `s -> s` is `T -> T`, whereas `(StringBuilder s) -> s.append()` could be `StringBuilder -> ()`, which satisfies the `void` requirement.

Comment: how about line where **messages.stream().forEach(s-> s); ** where i am not returning anything explicitly , why compiler doesn't assume it is void?

Comment: `s` cannot be a statement, so cannot be `void`

Answer (score 1):

`Stream.forEach(Consumer)` takes a consumer which implements one method

```
void accept(Object o);
```

i.e. it can't return anything.

If you want to return something you have to do something with the value returned.

Answer (score 1):

You said

> if we don't include code after "->" in curly braces that value will be returned implicitly

But that's not quite accurate. Rather, if you do not include curly braces, then, *if* a value *could* be be returned, then it will be returned implicitly. However, if a value should not be returned, because, for example, the functional interface method has a `void` return value, then the compiler will see that and not attempt to implicitly return anything.

In this case, [forEach](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-) accepts a [Consumer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html), whose return type is `void`, which is why you are getting compile errors when you attempt to return a value from it explicitly.

Comment: messages.stream().forEach(s-> s); // doesn't work , Void methods cannot return a value

Comment: @Makarand.Thorat the only possible type for `s -> s` is `T -> T`.